# Dynamic loading of sprites from JSON file does not work

Tags: unity-game-engine

The Unity project I am building is targeting iOS, Android and Windows X64.

**Problem**
In one of my scenes, I use a JSON file to load some sprites located in the Resources folder dynamically during runtime. The problem I currently have is this: When I run the game in the Unity Editor, it behaves as expected (the sprites are dynamically loaded and displayed in the scene). But when I run it on any of the three platforms (on real hardware) the sprites are not loaded/displayed in the scene. Static sprites are loaded though.

**Setup**
The scene is kind of a level selection screen. For every level, a sprite is displayed. The sprite and the number of sprites displayed is based on a JSON file that is read when the scene starts. Here is a screenshot to give you a better impression:

[image]

In one of the game objects's `Start`callback I run the code to read the JSON data:

```cs
var sceneSelectionInfoList = JsonHelper.GetSceneSelectionInfoForLanguage(GameLanguage.German);
```

The JSONHelper class so far (uses JSON.NET for Unity asset from the Asset Store):

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public static class JsonHelper
{
    private const string SceneDataIndexFilename = "Assets/Resources/SceneData/SceneDataIndex.json";

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public static List<SceneSelectionInfo> GetSceneSelectionInfoForLanguage(GameLanguage language)
    {
        var sceneSelectionInfoList = new List<SceneSelectionInfo>();

        // Open scene selection index
        var sceneDataIndexEntries = GetSceneDataIndexEntries(SceneDataIndexFilename);

        foreach (var sceneDataIndexEntry in sceneDataIndexEntries)
        {
            Logger.LogInfo(sceneDataIndexEntry.Filename);
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(sceneDataIndexEntry.Filename))
            {
                var jsonData = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                var jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
                var id = jObject.SelectToken("id").ToString();
                var basePath = jObject.SelectToken("basePath").ToString();
                var sceneSelectionImage = basePath + jObject.SelectToken("dragAndDrop.sceneSelectionImage");
                string title = null;

                switch (language)
                {
                    case GameLanguage.English:
                        title = jObject.SelectToken("titleEN").ToString();
                        break;
                    case GameLanguage.French:
                        title = jObject.SelectToken("titleFR").ToString();
                        break;
                    case GameLanguage.SwissGerman:
                        title = jObject.SelectToken("titleSG").ToString();
                        break;
                    case GameLanguage.Spanish:
                        title = jObject.SelectToken("titleES").ToString();
                        break;
                    case GameLanguage.German:
                        title = jObject.SelectToken("titleDE").ToString();
                        break;
                    case GameLanguage.Italian:
                        title = jObject.SelectToken("titleIT").ToString();
                        break;
                }

                var sceneSelectionInfo = new SceneSelectionInfo();
                sceneSelectionInfo.SceneId = id;
                sceneSelectionInfo.SceneSelectionImage = sceneSelectionImage;
                sceneSelectionInfo.Title = title;
                sceneSelectionInfoList.Add(sceneSelectionInfo);
            }
        }

        return sceneSelectionInfoList;
    }

    private static List<SceneDataIndexEntry> GetSceneDataIndexEntries(string sceneDataIndexFilename)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(sceneDataIndexFilename))
        {
            var jsonData = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Logger.LogInfo(jsonData);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SceneDataIndexEntry>>(jsonData);
        }
    }
}
```

Just for completeness: The `SceneSelectionInfo` class is just a data container (DTO) holding some values to pass around:

```cs
public class SceneSelectionInfo
{
    public string SceneId;
    public string SceneSelectionImage;
    public string Title;
}
```

Here are the paths to the JSON files and sprites, relative to the Unity project folder:

**Sprite Path:**
`Assets/Resources/SceneData/AfternoonAtTheBeach/DragAndDrop/SceneSelection.png`

**JSON File Path:**
`Assets/Resources/SceneData/AfternoonAtTheBeach/SceneData.json`

Here is the snipped from the JSON file (`basePath` and `sceneSelectionImage` together build up the path to the sprite to be loaded):

```cs
{
  "id": "AfternoonAtTheBeach",
  "basePath": "SceneData/AfternoonAtTheBeach/",
  "titleEN": "Afternoon at the beach",
  "titleFR": "Après-midi sur la plage",
  "titleSG": "Namitag am Strand",
  "titleES": "Tarde en la playa",
  "titleDE": "Nachmittag am Strand",
  "titleIT": "Pomeriggio in spiaggia",
  "dragAndDrop": {
    "sceneSelectionImage": "DragAndDrop/SceneSelection",
    "levels": [
      {
        "backgroundImage": "DragAndDrop/Graphics/Level1/Background",
        "items": [
          {
            "image": "DragAndDrop/Graphics/Level1/Ball",
            "dropPosX": -623,
```

The code to load the sprites (after having read the path from JSON file):

```cs
  var sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(sceneSelectionInfo.SceneSelectionImage);
  swiperItem.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = sprite;
```

**What I have checked so far**

- I refer to sprites by using relative paths, starting from the Assets/Resources directory, no file extensions (see sprite path example above).
- I have disabled Library Caching in Unity Cloud Build to avoid issues with old build artifacts (so every time I build, I do a proper, clean build)
- I can locally build all three platforms (Unity reports it as "Build successful")
- I am using LoadSceneMode.Single (default)
- I am using the same Unity version locally and in Unity Cloud Build: 2018.3.0f2

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: This is a complex problem so here's some stuff you can update your question with: What are the full paths to your JSON file as well as your sprite (in relation to the unity project)?  What's your code for loading the JSON look like? Do you have any complex async operations or coroutines running during the scene transition? How about any statics that could end up in a bad state?  Anything scene A depends on during initialization (`Awake()` and `Start()` methods)? Are you using `LoadSceneMode.Single` or `LoadSceneMode.Additive`? Have you tried switching to `SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync()`?

Comment: @Foggzie Thanks for your feedback. I have added more details to the question. I hope this makes it more clear. Regarding coroutines: Yes, I have some (but none of them run async). See example code.

Comment: Have you considered that / is not always the path delimiter and should be the one appropriate?

Comment: @BugFinder Hm, no I didn't. Are there any known problems with forward slashes? Thx.

Comment: Windows uses backslashes - you can always pick up the relevant one with Path.PathSeparator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two major issues here are 1) the way your JSON file is being loaded and 2) the way your manager object destroys itself.

---

For the JSON file:

You're using `StreamReader` which is a C# tool for reading from a file system. This isn't exactly how Unity's "Resources" system works. Since it exists under the "Assets" directory, your Editor can find it just fine; that's *where* it exists in the file system it's running under. When you make a device build, anything under a "Resources" directory is packaged into the build and *must* be accessed via the `Resources` API.

You have two options here:  You can replace your usage of `StreamReader` with a `Resources.Load<TextAsset>` call and make sure you use "*SceneData/SceneDataIndex*" (note: no file extension) instead of the version with "*Assets/Resources*".  You're other option is to place the JSON asset in a folded named "*Assets/StreamingAssets*" and then use [`Application.streamingAssetsPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html) to load it with `StreamReader`.  The streaming assets path with allow it to be loaded with regular C# file loading conventions as it'll be placed at a readable file system path.

Some notes: `Resources` API calls *MUST* use forward slashes (/) no matter the platform.  When using file system-based loaders like `StreamReader`, you should use `Path.Combine` or `Path.PathSeparator` to ensure you have the correct slashes.

---

Now for the second load of Scene A.  It's difficult to be certain what your issue is here without knowing the exact layout of your game object hierarchy but my assumption is that your `GameManager` script is sitting on an important `GameObject` and you're destroying it with:

```
else if (Instance != this)
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

This will destroy the game object, all scripts on it, *and all of it's children* and all scripts on them.  If you change that to `Destroy(this)`, it'll only remove the script from the object and leave your game object hierarchy intact.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response. In fact, your tip regarding JSON and Resources.Load solved my problem with the missing sprites. So that is good. Awesome! I am currently investigating the second issue. Keep you posted.

Comment: Is it ok for you, if I move the sexond problem (scene A) not loaded into a separate SO question? After that, you then just  move your answer part over to the new one. Finally, I can mark your answer here as correct.

Comment: Ok, I have split the questions apart. Here's the link to the other SO question. Just move your part of the post over there. Also added some more details to the problem description. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54775006/scene-not-properly-loaded-when-switching-back-and-forth  Thanks alot!